# While subnetting Class B address how to find out subnets number?

Tags: networking, ip

In this question why we subtract 2 from 2^3 while calculating number of subnets. While in CCNA books 2 is not subtracted?

```
172.16.0.0 /19
Subnets 2^3 -2 = 6
Hosts 2^13 -2 = 8190
Block Size 256-224 = 32
```

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking doesn't use network classes. Please let them rest in peace.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to Subnet the Class B 172.16.0.0 to a / 19 subnet, you add 3 bits to the default Class B netmask (which is /16)

The number of subnet available is 2^3 = 8 Subnets.

Concerning the number of Hosts you can have per subnet, it is 2^13-2 
The number 13 comes from 32 (number of bit in a netmask) - (number of bits affected to the MASK part 19)

You substract 2 for each subnet because the first host and the last host are reserved for Network and Broadcast address.

If i don't answer your question, please give more information about what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This is for your subnet mask

```
Address:   172.16.0.0            10101100.00010000.000 00000.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.224.0 = 19    11111111.11111111.111 00000.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.31.255            00000000.00000000.000 11111.11111111
=>
Network:   172.16.0.0/19         10101100.00010000.000 00000.00000000 (Class B)
Broadcast: 172.16.31.255         10101100.00010000.000 11111.11111111
HostMin:   172.16.0.1            10101100.00010000.000 00000.00000001
HostMax:   172.16.31.254         10101100.00010000.000 11111.11111110
Hosts/Net: 8190                  (Private Internet)
```